# Receiving message from Exchange Server with Unification Engine

Tags: exchangewebservices, unificationengine

What request and response I've to made with Exchange Connector and [Unification Engine](https://developer.unificationengine.com/) for receiving messages from Exchange Server, and also tell me How do connector knows that Connection is removed. I want the answer in order of what and how request and response follows the communication in order to receiving message and also provide the respective curl commands with json sample data, if possible. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A sample api call to unificationengine for retrieving  messages is

curl -XPOST https://apiv2.unificationengine.com/v2/message/retrieve -u USER_ACCESSKEY:USER_ACCESSSECRET --data "{\"uri\":\"unified://UNIQUE_CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER\", \"startindex\":\"1\",  \"entriesperpage\":1}" -k

The sample response data for this api call will be

{"Status":{"UNIQUE_CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER":{"status":200,"info":"OK"}},"messages":{"UNIQUE_CONNECTION_IDENTIFIER":[{"uri":"","mid":"","timestamp":"","sender":{"connector":"","name":"","address":"","uri":""},"returnPath":{"connector":"","address":"","uri":""},"receivers":[{"connector":"","name":"","address":"","uri":""}],"subject":"","date":"","userAgent":"","headers":"","parts":[{"id":"","contentType":"","type":"","data":"","size":"","sort":""}]}]}]}}

The connector will receive a command from unificationengine like this

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://CONNECTOR_KEY:CONNECTOR_SECRET@CONNECTOR_ENDPOINT/v2/message/retrieve –data "{\"uri\":\"CONNECTOR_SCHEMA://SERVICE_ACCESS_TOKEN:SERVICE_ACCESS_SECRET@CONNECTOR.com\",\"apiToken\":\"SERVICE_OAUTH_KEY:SERVICE_OAUTH_SECRET\", \"entriesperpage\":1,\"startindex\":\"1\" }" -k

Comment: could you pls tell me about other requests from UE to connector for fetching messages, and request for connector to stop to receiving messages and the same for the response from connector to UE.

Comment: The unificationengine sends the following requests to the connector 

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://CONNECTOR_KEY:CONNECTOR_SECRET@CONNECTOR_ENDPOINT/v2/message/retrieve –data "{\"uri\":\"CONNECTOR_SCHEMA://SERVICE_ACCESS_TOKEN:SERVICE_ACCESS_SECRET@CONNECTOR.com\",\"apiToken\":\"SERVICE_OAUTH_KEY:SERVICE_OAUTH_SECRET\", \"entriesperpage\":1,\"startindex\":\"1\" }" -k



    Unificationengine is not sending any request to connector automatically, if any requests come from the app unificationengine sends to the connector.

Comment: Yes I know that, If any request comes from App then UE will forward the request by make some changes in it to the connector, But I want to know In what form it will comes to Connector from UE whenever APP requested to UE for all possible cases, and how many types of these requests are possible? or all requests are same as above curl command??

Comment: The unificationengine will send a post request to /v2/message/retrieve in connector with the following parameters {\"uri\":\"\",\"apiToken\":\"\", \"entriesperpage\":1,\"startindex\":\"1\" }. All the request having the same parameters.

Comment: but where is those message ID goes, for each of which UE will request to get their messages data?? As you have told me this is two step process, in which first UE request to fetch IDs of let say first 100 messages then UE will request for any particular IDs of them to fetch their message data???